# How is an OpenID Client supposed look up the OpenID delegate?

Tags: html, openid

I just noticed that stackoverflow had problems with my OpenID delegate and I noticed that this was caused by my website not using a `<html>` and `<head>` section.

Now even though this is valid HTML the question is if it's valid for OpenID delegate lookups.  The official stuff I was able to find on the website just talks about “the head section” of the HTML document, which however by HTML4/5 standards is implicit.

I'm now interested if the bug is in the way I declared the delegate or the stackoverflow OpenID implementation.

The not working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<title>Index &raquo; Armin Ronacher</title>
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://mitsuhiko.myopenid.com/">
<meta content="Zine" name="generator">
<!-- more link/meta stuff here -->

<!-- page contents here -->
<div class="header">
```

The working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Index &raquo; Armin Ronacher</title>
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://mitsuhiko.myopenid.com/">
<meta content="Zine" name="generator">
<!-- more link/meta stuff here -->
</head>

<!-- page contents here -->
<div class="header">

<!-- at the very end of the page -->
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like the same behavior exists with python-openid.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is assumed that an HTML page should have a HEAD tag. Most do, even if it's not strictly required by some standards.

However, the OpenID standard seems to [require](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#anchor4) its tags to be placed in the HEAD tag. Do other sites detect your OpenID when it's not in HEAD?

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in your HTML page that declares the delegate.  The HTML and HEAD tags are required to be around the delegate tag for a very good security reason.  If this were not required, then many web pages like wiki's and blog pages could be hijacked for their identity merely by leaving a comment that included a specially crafted tag.

The "head section" referred to by OpenID is indeed the HEAD tag in an HTML page.  Although I haven't read the entire beefy thing, I'd be drop-dead surprised if the HTML spec itself didn't mandate a surrounding HTML tag, and that all META tags must be within a HEAD tag.  In my opinion, the OpenID spec doesn't go into detail about all the HTML requirements because it's a spec about OpenID and not HTML, but "head section" is a reference to the HTML spec, just as it references many other specs.

In conclusion, I believe StackOverflow.com is doing the right thing.

Comment: As I said.  The HTML spec does not require it.  You can check it yourself with a validator.  The head section is implicit.  It basically means that a <link> / <meta> tag can only appear inside <head> and thus it's considered part of a <head> tag even if not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to find on the website just talks about “the head section” of the HTML document, which however by HTML4/5 standards is implicit.

Where did you find this?  I searched through the standards and didn't find any mention of the "head section" (it talks about the "head element"); the closest I came on a broader search was that most implementations are lax in requiring an explicit `<html>` and `<head>`, but this was presented more as a case of magnanimously accepting non-compliant documents than as a part of the standard.

Comment: The reference i found: http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#anchor4

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on getopenid.com :

"If you have a blog or homepage you'd like to use as your OpenID, you don't have to set up a server! Just copy the following into the head part of your HTML or XHTML, and use that URL.

link rel="openid.server" href="http://getopenid.com/action/authenticate/"
link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://getopenid.com/YOURIDENTITY/"

Note that you cannot use secure signons with this URL unless you have your own SSL server. Sites will also see you as a different person than when you directly use your identity from GetOpenID.com."

I think you have to replace getopenid.com with your OpenID provider and YOURIDENTITY with
your OpenID identity.

Comment: Whiel there's technicly nothing wrong in what you say, you fail to realize that www.myopenid.com/server is his OpenID proveder and mitsuhiko.myopenid.com is his OpenID identity. That is because MyOpenID uses a YOURIDENTITY.myopenid.com format for the OpenID identities.